# Sending Form Data with the native node module

Tags: node.js, http, multipartform-data

for my current project I have to send form-data from my lambda function to an api endpoint. The api endpoint essentially expects two images (that it compares with one another) and a key. As mentioned before, I somehow seem unable to send the correct form-data to the api endpoint. I checked out postman, and it seems to have worked alright, but something doesn't seem to work in my function. I presume it must be related the form-data string that I'm sending. Below you can find a shortened version of the function (I excluded the two image files), but somehow I'm getting an error back telling me that the api cannot read the key property:

```
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const httpPromise = (protocol, params, postData) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const requestModule = protocol === 'http' ? http : https;
        const req = requestModule.request(params, res => {
            // grab request status
            const statusCode = res.statusCode;
            if(statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 299) {
                throw new Error('Request Failed with Status Code:', statusCode);
            }

            let body = '';
            // continuosly update data with incoming data
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', data => body += data);

            // once all data was received
            res.on('end', () => resolve(body));
        })

        // write data to a post request
        if(typeof(params.method) === 'string' && params.method === 'POST' && postData) {
            req.write(postData)
        }


        // bind to the error event
        req.on('error', err => reject(err));

        // end the request
        req.end();
    })
}

const controller = async () => {
    const apiKey = "00000000";
    const options = {
        hostname: '***"
        port: 80,
        path: '***'
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {"content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"}
    }
    const postData = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key\"\r\n\r\00000000\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"
    let result = await httpPromise('http', options, postData)
    console.log(result);
}
```

yeah, so somehow it just doesn't seem to recognise the key in the `postData` string. I have tried various different combinations but just can't seem to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so for anyone who might also face the same issue, it took me a little but figured out what the issue was. I didn't set the Content-Length header, which then in turn meant that node automatically added the Transfer-Encoding Header and set its value to chunk. This broke the receiving api and resulted in the issue. Setting the Content-Length header to the correct length and setting the Transfer-Encoding Header to an empty string solved my issue here (but I think one could also simply omit the transfer-encoding header once you defined the Content-Length Header).

Answer (score 1):

The default http and https libraries are kind of wordy and annoying.

Would recommend using the ***request*** library instead. Read more [here](https://github.com/request/request)

In which case, to make the request, you can simply write it as :

```
var request = require('request');

var formData = {
  // Pass a simple key-value pair
  my_field: 'my_value',
}

request.post({url:'http://service.com/upload', formData: formData}, (err, response, body) => {
   // Handle response here
});
```

Comment: !!! IMPORTANT UPDATE!!
Request - Simplified HTTP client is fully deprecated, since Feb 11th, 2020